# Worklight 6.3 project upgrade to MFP 7,1 iPad Environment unable to run

Tags: ios, ipad, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I face a problem when upgrading my project from Worklight 6.3 to MFP 7.1. I'm using MFP 7.1 to build an iPad environment with Worklight 6.3 source code (include using Worklight SDK). Besides that, I'm also copy ***WorklightSDK*** folder and files(e.g. libWorklightStaticLibProject.a) to the MFP 7.1 iPad project.

When I run the iPad environment, I get an error ***"Failed to load webpage with error: The URL can’t be shown"***   and the screen is stop at IBM landing page.

[image]

Anyone can guide or teach me to fix this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Its not clear how you went through the upgrade. You mention "with Worklight 6.3 source code (include using Worklight SDK). Besides that, I'm also copy WorklightSDK folder and files".
Did you create a new 7.1 ipad environment and copy only the javascript source code from 6.3?  Did you copy the source code to "common" folder or directly to the iPad environment?

Answer (score 0):

> Besides that, I'm also copy WorklightSDK folder and files(e.g. libWorklightStaticLibProject.a) to the MFP 7.1 iPad project.

What do you mean by that? Is this a Hybrid app or a Native app?

- In case of a Hybrid app I suggest for you to try and delete the native folder and re-build the project.
- In case of a Native app I suggest that you will remove the WorklightSDK folder from the native project, create a new NativeAPI project in MobileFirst Studio and copy the newly generated WorklightSDK folder to the native project.